# p-tablecheckbox and p-tableheadercheckbox

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a table which checkbox header and on checking the checkbox only few rows base on the condition need to be checked and on unchecking the box selected checks need to be disappear.

HTML

```
<p-table [value]="_rows" [columns]="columns" [(selection)]="selectedRows">
    <p-tableHeaderCheckbox id="selectAllRows" (click)="selectRow()"></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
    <p-tableCheckbox [value]="row" (click)="selectRow()" [disabled]="row.userDefined==='N'">
        </p-tableCheckbox
></p-table>
```

JS

```
selectRow() {
    this.selectedRows = this.selectedRows.filter(value => value.flag === 'Y');
    this.selectedEvent.emit(this.selectedRows);
}
```

Comment: <!-- html -->
<p-table [value]="_rows" [columns]="columns" [(selection)]="selectedRows">
<p-tableHeaderCheckbox id="selectAllRows"  (click)="selectRow()"></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
<p-tableCheckbox [value]="row" (click)="selectRow()" [disabled]="row.userDefined==='N'"></ptableCheckbox>
<!-- js -->
  selectRow() {
    this.selectedRows = this.selectedRows.filter(value => value.flag === 'Y');
    this.selectedEvent.emit(this.selectedRows);
}

Comment: Hi , have you check my answer if it work for you  ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`p-tableheadercheckbox` component has it one logic to set all rows to the `selectedRows` then this mean all items is selected you can check it logic [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/table/table.ts)

you can use a `p-checkbox` a bind `selectRow` to click event will do the job you desire

*component*

```js
  selectRow(checkValue) {
    if (checkValue) {
      this.selectedRows = this.cars.filter(value => value.year < 2000);
    } else {
      this.selectedRows = [];
    }
  }
```

*template*

```html
<p-table [value]="cars" [columns]="cols" [(selection)]="selectedRows">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
      <th>
        <p-checkbox (click)="selectRow(e.checked)" #e></p-checkbox>
      </th>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>

        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
      <td>
            <p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData" [disabled]="rowData.year > 2000">
        </p-tableCheckbox>

      </td>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>

        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-table-selection-checkbox)

Comment: Is it possible to detect if the `p-tableCheckbox` is checked?

Comment: How to programmatically change check/uncheck ptableheadercheckbox value?

Comment: I caught a problem here, the code work fine, but, when I click on the header checkbox and there are selectable rows in the tab, it doesn't get checked